# Creating external directory results in blank file

Tags: android

This is fairly straightforward: I'm trying to create an app-specific directory, but the last folder in the path is created as a file. Below is my current snippet of code:

```
public static File getExternalPath(Context context) {
    File dir = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
    if(!dir.exists()) {
        if(!dir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("VideoPod", "Could not create directory");
        }
    }
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] {dir.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);
    return dir;
}
```

The returned path is `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package>/files`, but `files` is shown as a file rather than a directory. Is there a reason for this? This is on KitKat, so I do not need read or write permissions, to my knowledge.

Comment: `getExternalFilesDir(null)` why null?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29), supplying null results in a returned file that will be a path to a sub-directory of the given type

Comment: so it must be exist. no need of `dir.exist()` and `dir.mkdirs()` never be called

Comment: @Raggeth : what do you mean by `files is shown as a file rather than a directory` ?

Answer (score 0):

After digging around a bit more, I found that the folders were being created correctly, just not in the intended external storage area.